# Auth0 - enriching data with user information

Tags: node.js, jwt, identity, auth0

I need my API to return objects that contain some user info. For example:
`api/comment/123` needs to return:

```
{
    id: 123,
    author: {
         id: 'googleblahblah|123456789',
         name: 'James Bond'
    }
}
```

Normally I would just join the user and the comment table, though in this case I can't. My app's database stores the user id, though the name (and other user stuff) is stored in Auth0.

Obviously making an API call to Auth0 to 'enrich' objects on every API call is not plausible.

Do I cache all / some some user info on my app server? Have only the user ID in the API result and let the client enrich the data?

How do people handle this?

Comment: I don't know Auth0, but you tagged JWT, can't you put the name of the user in it?

Comment: I think you can create a rule that would update the user info on the fly. The only issue is that it is executed on the auth0 side so you'd have to create an api on your end that would expose the data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think there is an ultimate solution for this problem.

What I did was creating a `user` table with `user id` and `user name` in my own database. Whenever somebody logs via Auth0 in I would create or update the logged-in user information in that table with the OAuth token information.

After that you could join the tables as you stated.